# How to show all departments where school name = x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Upon the creation of a department, users have the option to add the name of a school. On the show page of the school, I want to show all the departments with the school of that name.

My school controller's show action looks like this:

```
def show
  @department = Department.where(:school == 'university of connecticut')
end
```

This obviously isn't working. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Notice that `:school == 'university of connecticut'` expands to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either if these should give you the expected results:

```
@department = Department.where(school: 'university of connecticut').first
```

or

```
@department = Department.where('school = ?', 'university of connecticut').first
```

`where` takes either a hash or a SQL statement.  Note that in the first example, we're using the shortcut hash method when using a symbol `symbol: value`, which is equivalent to `:symbol => value`

Also, keep in mind that `where` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not an ActiveRecord object.  You'll need to add `.first` or another form of `.find` if you wish to receive an ActiveRecord object directly.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. However now, when I try to call `<%= @departments %>` in my school show view, I get `#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Department:0x00000104a9a9c0>` . Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: See the update to my answer (you have to add `.first` or another method which returns an ActiveRecord object)

Comment: `<%= @departments.first %>`

Comment: Unfortunately, the page just goes blank after adding the `.first` @Donovan

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have a typo and there isn't a `Department` record where school matches `university of connecticut` exactly.  Did you maybe mean, `Connecticut`?  Searches with `Postgresql` are case-sensitive.

Comment: Actually... I noticed the school name isn't being saved when the department is created... I've gotta do something with permitting params, right? Where can I find that?

Comment: That's a separate question, but yes, in your controller.  Look up Rails4 `strong_parameters` for details on that.

Answer (score 2):

You're close:

```
Department.where(school: 'university of connecticut').first
```

i.e. normal hash syntax.

Comment: Great! This works. And I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes. But now, when I try to call `<%= @departments %>` in my school show view, I get `#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Department:0x00000104a9a9c0>` . Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @DylanRichards You are a liar.

Comment: Reason I decided not to accept this answer is because another user provided me with an answer that works and proceeded to help me with consequential issue @sawa

Comment: @DylanRichards I know. But that does not change the fact that you lied